# React include a onClick to a span

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to include a onClick option to my span.

I have the following method that returns a span

```
setCondition = () => {
    const condition = this.props.condition;
    if(condition) {
        return (
            <div className="hidden-xs">
                <span className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
                <span className="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-2x" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="hidden-xs">
                <span className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" />
                <span className="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to add the method below when I click on one of the span.

```
const update = (cond) => {
   console.log(cond);
}
```

I tried to do:

```
<span onClick={this.update(true)} className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
```

But it nothing happens when I click.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call function `this.update(true)` while binding. Bind just the function without call like `this.update`.

```
<span onClick={this.update} className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
```

Check [example in React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

---

Or use double arrow function if you need to pass fixed parameter

```
const update = (cond) => () => {
   console.log(cond);
}

<span onClick={this.update(true)} className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
```

---

Or you can use anonymous function

```
const update = (cond) => {
   console.log(cond);
}

<span onClick={this.update(true)} className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
```

but as the documenation says:

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders.
>
> Source: [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: But I need to pass an argument to the function

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
<span onClick={() => this.update(true)} ... />
```

`onClick` receive function and you provide it with the return value of update

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an anonymous function like this:

```js
<span onClick={() => this.update(true)} .../>
```

Comment: This will keep allocating new references due the anonymous function.

Comment: @Jax-p I don't get it, how's that?

Comment: @Francisco Jax-p's comment is not about the validity of the solution. It is the fact that you are passing an anonymous function into your click handler, which has performance penalties. It is better to make it a named function.